# iOS - UITableView scrollbar goes out of screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitableview

I am new to iOS and i have some serious problem i don't know why this happened, i also tried to find out the reason behind this but i failed.

I am creating a app in iPhone which take tweet of particular user using twitter api, i have no problem in getting the json data, also able to display it in UITableView in iOS 6 using storyboard, i had changed the row height to 200 px, so that i can display user name text tweet and image.

But when I scroll up or down the `UITableViewCell` the scrollbar goes out of the screen.

What may be the reason?how can I fix it?

ScreenShots

First it shows like this when the app loads the scrollbar takes the full screen

[image]

then when i scroll it get out of the screen

[image]

at last it completely gets out of screen

[image]

UITableView delegate methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSMutableArray *name,*time,*tweet,*image;

    name=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    time=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    tweet=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    image=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    for (User *userModel in self.user) {
        [name addObject:userModel.nameStr];
        [image addObject:userModel.imageStr];

    }

    for (Json *jsonModel in self.json) {
        [tweet addObject:jsonModel.tweetStr];
        [time addObject:jsonModel.timeStr];


    }

    // Fetch using GCD
    dispatch_queue_t downloadThumbnailQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Get Photo Thumbnail", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadThumbnailQueue, ^{
        NSString *imageURL=[image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
            image.image=img;

            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            [spinner stopAnimating];

        });
    });

    self.labelName = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    [self.labelName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];


   self.labelTime = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];
    [self.labelTime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [time objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];




     self.labelTweet = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:12];
    [self.labelTweet setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tweet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];


    cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    return cell;

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGFloat rowHeight=self.labelName.frame.size.height+self.labelTime.frame.size.height+self.labelTweet.frame.size.height+50;
        return rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the screen shot????

Comment: can you post some code my friend?

Comment: cant understand what you mean by scrollbar goes out of the screen

Comment: Can you shw your code and some screen shot

Comment: how to take a screen shot

Comment: please show me screenshot

Comment: you need to post tableView delegate method.since your table cell resizes when scroll.that may be the problem.

Comment: added my screen shots

Comment: Thanks to all, i got it   
adding this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath makes it proper
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

Comment: tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480); 480 is a fullscreen height,the activity bar height is 20,so set height 460

Answer (score 2):

Well scroll goes out of the screen means the tableView frame is larger than the screen size

Set the frame of tableview properly using `setFrame:` method

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check the height of the UITableView. Show the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `ScrollBar` goes down as the `Height of TableView` is larger then the `UIView` in which you are adding TableView. Adjust the frame according to your view then the `ScrollBar` will not disappear.